# Prove if cycles are enough to prevent string transformation

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

**Interview question.**

Prove if all characters in the transformation from string A to string B are in some cycles then you cannot perform such transformation and you would need 
an additional character per cycle.

The above was the last question in the interview but here is what went on:

You are given two strings A and B. You need to return `True` if you can transform string A to string B one character at a time and you are only allowed to use the characters in the string A and B.
E.g. `foo` translated to `baa` means that `f -> b`, `o -> a`. No additional characters can be used.

Another example where you will return `True`: `A = ghijk`, `B = hkjki`

```
A = ghijk

Transformation: j -> h gives ghihk 

Transformation: i -> j gives ghjhk

Transformation: k -> i gives ghjhi

Transformation: h -> k gives gkjki

Transformation: g -> h gives hkjki = B
```

An example where you return `False`: cannot convert `abc` to `bca`. Cannot convert `abc` to `bac` also.
This is because `abc -> bbc` using `a->b` transformation. Then `b` translated to `c` would give `ccc` and you will not be able to get `bca`.

The following is the algorithm that we came up with: 
If both the strings are the same I returned `True` i.e. `abc` can be converted to `abc`.

If there exist cycles where all the vertices form part in at least one cycle then return False else return True.
E.g.  `abc` cannot be converted to `bca` because `a` maps to `b`  `b` maps to `a` hence a cycle and `a` maps to `a`  which is a self loop another cycle.
`foo` can be mapped to `baa` because there is no cycle.

`ghijk` can be mapped to `hkjki` where `g -> h -> k -> i -> j ->k`. There is a cycle only from k to i to j to k but the other characters g and h are not part of a cycle.

Note that converting `abc` to `bca` can be done by having one more character i.e. `abc -> xbc -> xba -> xca -> bca` where you have the additonal transformation `a -> x -> b`

Was asked to prove: 
Prove if there exist cycles where all the vertices form part in at least one cycle then return False else return True.
Prove whether you need an additional character per cycle if you return False.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have even one cycle $l_1 \to l_2 \to \ldots \to l_k \to l_1$, then, since I don't see an option to transform two letters at once, inevitably one of the letters [in the loop/cycle] will be transformed **first**. W.l.o.g. assume this is $l_1$. Then at the moment you are ready to transform $l_2$ you can't distinguish between original $l_2$ and transformed $l_1$.

Adding one character to the loop helps, but only if it is not a part of some other transformation, i.e. if there exists $l_1 \to l_2$, you can't have a rule $l_3 \to l_1 \to l_4$.

Let say, you have a loop $l_1 \to l_2 \to \ldots \to l_k \to l_1$, then you add the new rule $l_1 \to x \to l_2$. And apply $l_1 \to x$ first, then all the rules in the loop from end to start. $l_k \to l_1$, then $l_{k-1} \to l_k$, etc. then $l_2 \to l_3$ and finally $x \to l_2$.